# Ubuntu application switcher like ElementaryOS

Tags: application-switcher

I love the way ElementaryOS aplication switcher looks like (alt+tab) and i want the same efect on my Ubuntu 13.04. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thnks

Answer (score 2):

The answer was in the Application Switcher of the compizconfig settings manager as mentioned in [Dilmo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/326960/527764).

But a little tweaking was needed.

Here is what I did:

In the bindings tab disable <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> for the "next window" and "previous Window" and assign those to "Next Window (no popup)" and "Previous Window (no popup)".

In the General tab, set speed to 0.0, Timestep 0.1, Saturation 100, Brightness 100, opacity 10.

Now my application switch is blazing fast and no background windows are shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Install the compizconfig settings manager
2. Open up Advanced Settings (compizconfig)
3. Enable Application Switcher
4. Profit!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already done that, but what i want is same behaviour, (when pressing alt+tab) all applications disapear and show only one application while switching. thnks